# How to show logical values in rhandsontable as the check boxes on UI

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I have one question on how to show the logical values in rhandsontable as check boxes on UI. Here is the code originally from (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rhandsontable/vignettes/intro_rhandsontable.html).

```
library(rhandsontable)

DF = data.frame(val = 1:10, bool = TRUE, big = LETTERS[1:10],
                small = letters[1:10],
                dt = seq(from = Sys.Date(), by = "days", length.out = 10),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

col_highlight = 2
row_highlight = c(5, 7)

rhandsontable(DF, col_highlight = col_highlight, 
              row_highlight = row_highlight,
              width = 550, height = 300) %>%
  hot_cols(renderer = "
    function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
      Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
      
      tbl = this.HTMLWidgets.widgets[0]

      hcols = tbl.params.col_highlight
      hcols = hcols instanceof Array ? hcols : [hcols] 
      hrows = tbl.params.row_highlight
      hrows = hrows instanceof Array ? hrows : [hrows] 

      if (hcols.includes(col) && hrows.includes(row)) {
        td.style.background = 'red';
      }
      else if (hcols.includes(col)) {
        td.style.background = 'lightgreen';
      }
      else if (hrows.includes(row)) {
        td.style.background = 'pink';
      }
      
      return td;
  }")
```

As you can see, the bool column was not shown as the check boxex and they are not editable too. Does anyone know how to (1) show the logic column as check boxes on UI, and (2) how to make that column as editable? Any your input will be greatly apprreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you can't use a text renderer to render boolean values. You need to use `CheckboxRenderer` instead. Here is how to fix:

```r
library(rhandsontable)

DF = data.frame(val = 1:10, bool = TRUE, big = LETTERS[1:10],
                small = letters[1:10],
                dt = seq(from = Sys.Date(), by = "days", length.out = 10),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

col_highlight = 2
row_highlight = c(5, 7)

rhandsontable(DF, col_highlight = col_highlight, 
              row_highlight = row_highlight,
              width = 550, height = 300) %>%
    hot_cols(renderer = "
    function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    console.log(typeof value)
      if(typeof value === 'boolean') {
         Handsontable.renderers.CheckboxRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
      } else {
        Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
      }
     
      
      tbl = this.HTMLWidgets.widgets[0]
      console.log(value)
      hcols = tbl.params.col_highlight
      hcols = hcols instanceof Array ? hcols : [hcols] 
      hrows = tbl.params.row_highlight
      hrows = hrows instanceof Array ? hrows : [hrows] 

      if (hcols.includes(col) && hrows.includes(row)) {
        td.style.background = 'red';
      }
      else if (hcols.includes(col)) {
        td.style.background = 'lightgreen';
      }
      else if (hrows.includes(row)) {
        td.style.background = 'pink';
      }
      
      return td;
  }")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi lz100, thank you very much for your help. Yes, that is what I am exactly looking for. I really appreciate your solution.

Comment: @BoYu, great. Then would you please accept it as the best answer?

Comment: Hi lz100, I would love to do that, but I am not familar with the system. Could you please show me where and how I can accept as the best answer?  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @BoYu, [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) should be helpful

Comment: Hi lz100, thanks for sharing me with the rating link. I did it. Thanks you very much again for your help.